# How to append a series value using if...else in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame with around 10k Observation and few features.
Manually in excel file I can create a new column based on given data i.e.

```
 = IF(A = 0, 1, B)
```

where A, B are basically Column name.

Output of above formula would be appended on new column i.e. C.

I have used below Python code :

```
C = []

for x in df['A']:
    if x == 0:
        C.append(1)
    else:
        C.append(df['B'])
```

But the above output is giving me "unhashable type: 'Series'" Error.

Anyway to correct the above code

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a loop, use `np.where`:

```
import numpy as np
# as new column
df['C'] = np.where(df['A'].eq(0), 1, df['B'])
# as list
C = np.where(df['A'].eq(0), 1, df['B']).tolist()
```

or `mask`:

```
# as new column
df['C'] = df['B'].mask(df['A'].eq(0), 1)

# as list
C = df['B'].mask(df['A'].eq(0), 1).to_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to append the whole column - you need to append the value.
Try:

```
c = []
for a, b in zip(df['A'], df['B']):
    c.append(1 if a == 0 else b)
```